# How do i change the class of a DIV tag on Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I'm actually trying to do is to fill some questions with answers on JavaScript function call. But every time I incrementally add answers, it doesn't just find the questions with no answers but with as well. My solution is every time I give an answer to a question, i change it's div class so it wont be found next answer load.

Here is what iv'e got so far:

.mustache:

```
<div class="all-answers ui-sortable" id="question_{{order}}">
</div>
```

.js:

```
function addAnswers() {

    var test = $("#survey-ajax").find("#answers_from_prev .all-answers-prev");

    .
    .     (code adding answers)
    .

    // after answers are added, div class should be changed
    var allAnsPrev = $("#survey-ajax").find(".all-answers-prev");
    allAnsPrev.className="all-answers-prev_changed";

}
```

Something like that. Is that possible? or is there easier way doing it?

Comment: If you're using jQuery please update the tags on your question to include it.

Comment: Side note: "using MVC framework" means absolutely nothing as there are tons of MVC frameworks both server and client side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`allAnsPrev` is a jQuery object, but `className` is a DOM element property. Use the jQuery methods for changing classes.

```
allAnsPrev.removeClass("all-answers-prev").addClass("all-answers-prev_changed");
```

You could abbreviate this using `toggleClass`:

```
allAnsPrev.toggleClass("all-answers-prev all-answers-prev_changed");
```

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH SIR. YOU ARE THE REAL MVP.